# How do I change gradient color of text inside the Jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, linear-gradients

I have been looking everywhere for the correct code to change only the text (title)  within the Jumbotron.

Here's what I got:

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1 class="method2">Title here</h1>
            <p>Sub-heading</p>
        </div>
```

I want to change the gradient coloring of this title. I saw a css code somewhere that went like this:

```
h1.method2{
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1));
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1));
 }
```

The problem I'm facing is that the bottom portion of my "Title here" bit seems cut off a bit, so I tried re-adjusting the bottom margin but it didn't work that way either. All that did was push the sub-heading further below.

I am also not sure how exactly this gradient pattern works. There doesn't seem many explanations about font gradient coloring for bootstrap.

Can someone explain if I'm doing something wrong and how this works?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the css and you have it in your folder, go find the line

> .jumbotron .h1

in there just paste the code that you posted

> -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1));
>   -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1));

and that's it, if you're importing the css from their website you're going to have to overwrite it

Comment: Well not all the code was imported. Just the css bit there... the "h1.method2" was based off how it was written on the html and css code there.

I didn't "download" any css, just used the -webkit-mask-image code bit that was there. Is there some kind of import that I'm missing here? It still didn't work...

Comment: @OrangeLime but how are you importing bootstrap? It's in your bootstrap where you have to put that code, not in h1.method2, you have to put it under

.jumbotron h1,
.jumbotron .h1 {
  color: inherit;
}